# How to find out the reason why GetObject failed?

Tags: c++, winapi

According to MSDN, [GetObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144904(v=vs.85).aspx) returns 0 on failure. It does not say how to get additional information about the failure.

I've tried [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx), but it looks like it does not reflect the previous failure and returns 0 (i.e. `ERROR_SUCCESS`) instead.

How do I get the failure reason when `GetObject` fails?

Comment: According to the documentation, i don't think it gives a detailed reason. It just returns 0 on failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation [GetObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144904.aspx) will not set the last error code. This is not necessary either, since you can easily deduce, which parameter is wrong:

If a call to `GetObject` fails passing `NULL` for *lpvObject*, you know the handle is wrong (either a handle to an object that no longer exists, or is of an unsupported type).

If the previous call succeeded, and a following call with the same GDI object handle fails, you know that you are passing an inappropriate buffer (either too small, or not properly aligned on a 4-byte boundary).